# Generate combinations with repetition without using itertools

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I have very little experience with Computer Science and algorithm theory. I need to generate and print all combinations with repetitions for numbers 1..n of size k in lexicographic order. And I should do it without using itertools. I wrote simple code to create all combinations, but it's not enough to solve this task.

```
 
n, k = map(int, input().split())
    def gen (n, k, prefix):
        if len(prefix) == n:
            print(*prefix)
            return
       for c in range(1, n + 1):
            if c not in prefix:
                gen(n, k, prefix +[c])
    n1 = gen(n, k, [])
```

Sample Input

```
3 3
```

Sample Output

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 3 3
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 3 3
3 3 3
```

Pls help me to find the solution!

Comment: Why can't you use itertools?

Comment: My task excludes itertools usage. I have to implement recursive algorithm without itertools and its functions/methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive implementation:

```
def combrep(n, k, pos=0, start = 0, l = []):
    if pos == k:
        print(l)
    else:
        for i in range(start, n):
            combrep(n, k, pos+1, i, l + [i+1])

combrep(3,3)

[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: hmmm...seems really easy and logical, but output is different from sample, which is not right. And also there is another amount of combination: (n + k - 1)!/k! * (n - 1)!

Comment: @Ignat Sonets Ouch, I see that I misunderstand the problem. Some minutes, please

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement), it says that `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` roughly translates to this (minor edit so it takes an integer):

```
def combinations_with_replacement(n, r):
    pool = tuple(range(n))
    if not n and r:
        return
    indices = [0] * r
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i:] = [indices[i] + 1] * (r - i)
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

for i in combinations_with_replacement(3, 3):
    print(i)
```

```
for i in combinations_with_replacement(3, 3):
    print(i)
```

```
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 3)
(2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 3)
```

I can't imagine a simpler implementation. Why not start from there?